# Click header and expand text without using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: html, css, text

As pointed out in the title, my question is very simple: is there any way that I can achieve clicking on a header (title) and expand (and collapse) a text associated with it, without using JavaScript nor jQuery? Is there any browser compatible way of doing this (IE 6+ proof)?

I've made a very simple HTML+CSS site for a conference, and I would like to use JS only if necessary. So, I'm just asking if I can do it sticking only to HMTL/CSS, in a compatible way, of course.

The few solutions I've found are old or incompatible with some browser versions.

Comment: I would say your only options are HTML5, or JavaScript. Both of which violate one of your conditions.

Comment: @Samuel: how does HTML5 violate one of the conditions?

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, Samuel. I had the same doubt as daGUY. I'll have to support IE 6, some people are stil using it, so I'll choose using JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**IE6**-proof pure CSS solution?

## NO

[Leave the dead rest in their graves, don't try to make them run a marathon. That's what you're doing when you're asking for IE6 to do things like this.]

---

**IE7/8?**

Yes, there is one solution (the principle is the same one used in [this older demo of mine](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/U7Cyk/)), but it is not persistent (meaning that if you click anywhere else on the page, your expanded content will collapse) and it behaves a bit weird in IE7 (meaning that you have to hover off the clicked element after you click it in order to see your content expanding).

---

**IE9+ and the other browsers**?

**YES!** Also persistent. Same principle as the one I used [**here**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3157489).

---

**JavaScript/ jQuery method?**

**Yes!** See this: [a jQuery version of the same demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/yDfTq/).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, Ana. Unfortunately, some people still use IE 6 nowadays, so I'll just have to take them into account. As I thought, I'll really have to use JS.

Comment: Take into account the fact that jQuery is dropping support for IE6, 7 and 8 (so make sure you don't auto-update the jQuery version you'll use). I still recommend jQuery if you want to use JavaScript. IE is decent, but writing pure JavaScript for IE6 and 7 is a reason for headaches.

Comment: In fact, I need something more basic, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713059/expand-p-when-h1-is-clicked

Thanks again, Ana!

Answer (score 3):

You can do simple Hover dropdown menus with just HTML & CSS which are supported cross browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/fkS2z/

You can improve on this with fades or slidedowns with CSS transitions which are not supported in lower version of IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/N9fDy/1/

Not so much with clicking though.

Comment: Hello, StewD. I guess I'll have some compatibility issues with some IE versions (as always...) if using only HMTL + CSS, so I'll opt for JS. Nevertheless, thanks!